# No Ejecuta El VBS de dialogo sale error

Tags: vbscript

```
For i = 1 to 5
    wscript.StdOut.Write i
next
For i = 1 to 5
    wscript.StdOut.Write i
next
For i = 1 to 5
    wscript.StdOut.Write i
next
For i = 1 to 5
    wscript.StdOut.Write i
next
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alguna vez, hace tiempo me apareció ese error. En mi caso era porque estaba ejecutando el script mediante WSCript en el cual no existe la salida estandar.

Existen dos *Host* de ejecución para los scripts. Uno es **CScript.exe**, pensado para linea de comando y el otro es **WSCript.exe** pensado para ejecutarse mediante *GUI* (Doble click).

Para evitar este problema puedes ejecutar tu script con CScript.exe, por ejemplo desde una Ventana de comando pones

```
cscript miscript.vbs
```

O bien, puedes establecer como predeterminado el *Host* cscript, para ello desde una ventana de comando con permisos de administrador ejecuta

```
cscript //H:CScript
```

Para establecer Wscript como Host predeterminado, desde la ventana de comando con permisos de administrador ejecutas

```
cscript //H:WScript
```

O, por último, puedes utilizar `WScript.echo` en lugar de `StdOut`. Al utilizar `echo` automáticamente se mostrará el mensaje por línea de comando o mediante un cuadro de diálogo dependiendo de si se ejecutó el script mediante CScript.exe o WScript.exe respectivamente.

Saludos